# Chrome Extension Message Passing between background and content script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Im writing a chrome extension for instagram,my download upload Repost code work fine,

now i need Catch Requested Url and FormData or etc. Before sending ,

```
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(a) {});
```

or other listener

Then I want Catched Requested Url or formData Passing to Content script,

Thanks for ansvers.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue.

I added below permission in manifest file:

```
             +  "webRequest",
             + "webRequestBlocking",
```

After adding this codes the communication was done successfully.